# Retrieve blog posts through web service ?

Tags: android, web-services, blogger

Is there any similar way to retrieve blog posts in blogger as a web service ? I know there are plugins for workdpress like [this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-web-service/).

But I need to get data from blogger to use it in my android app.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer for my question. There is [Google data API](https://code.google.com/apis/blogger/docs/2.0/json/getting_started.html) which can access blogger information. We can use the API and get JSON out put.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Blogger provides RSS feeds for their blogs.

Comment: we do not have access to archive in rss feed.